# Safe way to perform DB script

Tags: postgresql, psql

If I am reading the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) correctly, issuing this command

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 database < script.sql
```

where `script.sql` starts with `BEGIN`

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE...
some other DDL...

COMMIT;
```

should mean that if one of the commands in `script.sql` fails, the whole script is rolled back?

(I am looking for a way to issue a DB upgrade that atomically succeeds or fails.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that's basically right. FYI, the ON_ERROR_STOP business is just a hint to `psql` that you want it to stop (and, in your case, effectively rollback by closing the connection) immediately upon an error, instead of flooding you with a bunch of messages like "ERROR:  current transaction is aborted" for each subsequent command in the transaction.

There are a few exceptions, see some hints in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13462942/1772673). But if you try to stick a command in your `script.sql` which is not allowed to run inside a transaction block, PostgreSQL should give you an error like "... cannot run inside a transaction block" and your transaction should get rolled back.

Of course, you'd be well advised to try your migration script on a test/backup instance (you do test your backups somewhere, right?) first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems the last sentence has been cut short, could you please finish it?

Comment: Fixed last sentence, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, all the scripts are first run on the test instance - my question goes in the direction of a tool that would first try the script and then actually run it, think `$ upgrade.sh script.sql`

Comment: Sure, you should be able to use `psql` as in your example to actually load in script.sql from inside your `upgrade.sh` script -- the exit code of `psql` should tell you whether the migration finished successfully or not. Oh, and one more tip -- it's a bit nicer to feed in your script.sql via the `--file` option to psql (easier for psql to pinpoint the line in the file which is bad in case of problems).

Comment: I am using the < so that I don't need to upload the script on the remote server beforehand...